# How would I add imformation to an "if" statement?

Tags: tcl

`if { $chan == $chan_(1) || $chan == $chan_(2) && $nick == $ircbotnick } {` .....more code

The chan is defined with `set chan_(1) "#1"` etc

but when I add additional fields ie `$chan == $chan_(3)` that third or 4th channel fails to work as the first two do. It's supposed to pick up irc chat announces but it works as I posted but when I add more channels to it it fails on the added channels and only works with the 2 original channels 1 and 2.

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: You don't show the code that fails to work and you don't indicate in what way it fails to work. That makes it very hard to guess the problem. My first thought is that you may not realize that && has higher priority than ||, so you may want to put the part before the && in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding more and more `$chan == ...` conditions, try creating a list and then check for list inclusion with `in`.

```
set valid_chans [list $chan_(1) $chan_(2) $chan_(3)]

if {$chan in $valid_chans && $nick == $ircbotnick } {
    ...
}
```

Adding additional channels to the `valid_chans` list is easy to do and the `if` statement does not need to change.